Redirect loop when accessing user page
It seems that after I changed my display name to include my Chinese name, trying to go to my user page (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/67/brc-寇百强) results in a 310 error - Too many redirects.  I've tried clearing my cookies and cache, but it didn't help.  The same error happens trying to access my page via .../user/67, but this simply redirects as well.  I assume this has something to do with the way the Chinese is encoded in the URL, but I don't know enough about this to really suggest anything more.

This is now fixed. An unfortunate code bug - sorry about that, and thanks for reporting it.

Hmmm, I asked Jeff and he said he wouldn't fix it. It looks like it works differently from other sites, where the Unicode stuff is just removed.

@NullUserException well, he was entirely correct; he didn't fix it! I did :p
